# Given a path to an executable, how can I determine when the program is launched without root privilege, and without polling /proc/

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a program that determines when a program would run on a Linux system given the path to it's executable without needing root privileges, or scanning /proc/. The reason I don't want to use root privilege is because my program should only look for processes launched by  the user that ran it, so I don't see why it should require escalated privilege.

I'm currently periodically scanning /proc/ as I've failed to find any other solution that satisfies my requirements, but it's a very slow way to go about things. The only other solutions that I've come up with are to use the proc connector which I really don't want to do since that requires root, or to use X11's CreateNotify which I also don't want to do since I want this program to run on Wayland as well.

Comment: Scanning /proc should be fast. Can you share your code - may be it can be improved. Also consider 'ps' - it has filters on user, command, etc. Trying to work with X11 CreateNotify likely to be much more effort, and will require a persistent connection to X (daemon like code), whereas looking at /proc can be done with regular program/

Comment: ok well let me rephrase it, it's not that it's slow but it's that ot seems like a waste of cpu cycles if that makes sense. The code runs well I'm just looking for ways to improve it. I'm confused on how I'd use ps tho, what exactly are you thinking of?

Comment: In general, better to reuse existing utilities (ps & friends) and not to re-implement. However, if you have a running solution, no point in beating the bushes here